# Make swagger.json editable in swashbuckle

Tags: c#, json, web-services, swagger

I'm making the documentation of a ASP.NET Web API with *Swagger*. The project contain some MVC Controllers and some API controllers (.NET Framework 4.7); to make this documentation I use a NuGet package called **swashbuckle**. Everything works fine (Swagger UI run fine and i can do get/post/put fine too).

The problem is: Now I want to make the json file(http://localhost:4444/swagger/docs/v1 generate a .json file of the Swagger UI) generated by swashbuckle **editable** through the website and document the results of the methods(get/post) in a .json files.

That my **SwaggerConfig.cs**:

```
    using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using Com.Deg.Web;
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using System;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace Com.Deg.Web
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
        {
            return String.Format(@"{0}\bin\Com.Deg.Web.xml", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        }

        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Deg API");
                        c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

**How can i do this ?**